# Error averaging in Neo4j using Cypher query language

Tags: neo4j, cypher, average

Hello i am trying to average values of a "Response" Node that are numbers (liking ratings). 
However when I query the following:

```
MATCH (p:Panelist)<-[BY_PANELIST]-(r:Response)[ON_ATTRIBUTE]->(a:Attribute)-[OF_ATTRIBUTETYPE]->(at:AttributeType)
WHERE a.name = 'Liking'
AND at.name = 'Hedonic'
RETURN avg(r)
```

I receive the following error:

Type mismatch: expected Float, Integer or Duration but was Node "RETURN avg(r)"

What do I need to change about the response to make it numerical?

Answer (score 0):

You have numerous apparent typos in your query, which I will attempt to fix in the query below (after making assumptions about what you intended).

But, regarding your main question: it does not make sense to get the average of nodes. You can only get the average of node (or relationship) *properties*.

For example, if a `Response` node has a `foo` property that you want to average:

```
MATCH (:Panelist)<-[:BY_PANELIST]-(r:Response)-[:ON_ATTRIBUTE]->(a:Attribute)-[:OF_ATTRIBUTETYPE]->(at:AttributeType)
WHERE a.name = 'Liking'
  AND at.name = 'Hedonic'
RETURN AVG(r.foo) AS avg_foo
```

Comment: ^ what is the attribute of `r` that you want to `avg()`? e.g. `r.height`. It's like saying "average my Alex!" ... what about them do you want to avg?

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. Ultimately i needed to know if the numbers should be a property instead of the node.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. All values are stored in properties, and nodes (and relationships) are containers for any number of properties.